# Citrix complete removal on Mac

Tags: macos, mac, citrix

I updated to Ventura OSX and I have huge problems. I already uninstalled all Citrix apps, followed every guide I found on the Internet to remove every remaining files in hidden folders etc. I even used Clean my Mac for removing everything. But about every 15 minutes a notification that you added some background items pops up.

Item appears in after login items.

I tried following without any further success:

https://macsecurity.net/view/326-citrix-receiver-uninstall
https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX134237/how-to-remove-files-remaining-on-system-after-uninstalling-receiver-for-mac
Clean my mac
nothing helped at all :/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYRA4.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hv0pO.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This is a current bug some users are experiencing. You might want to mark this topic as "Me too" since they have not put out a fix yet. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254341579

Here's an image from another user getting the same thing:

[image: Background Items Added Notifications]